# P/Invoke BSTR from unmanaged code

Tags: .net, vb.net, pinvoke

What should be the VB signature for the unmanaged function
void PopulateBSTR(BSTR outstring)?

The function PopulateBSTR does a SysAllocString and populates the string. Note the unmanagaed signature has the argument BSTR and not BSTR*. I can marshal the BSTR string using IntPtr signature when the C++ signature has BSTR* as the argument.

(The unmanaged code is an external dll which I cannot modify but I need to use.)

Comment: There is no scenario where *returning* a string through a passed BSTR argument (instead of BSTR*) is valid.  This legacy code can only have worked by accident although it is utterly unclear how that plane landed without turning into a ball of flames.  You ran out of that kind of luck.

Comment: @Hans is quite right. You need to go back to basics and work out what is really going on.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at [PInvoke.net](http://www.pinvoke.net/search.aspx?search=bstr&namespace=%5BAll%5D%5C), it looks like you need to use the [MarshallAs Attribute](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/oleaut32/RegisterTypeLib.html) to indicate that it should be treated as a `BSTR`.

Answer (score 0):

Need to specify `CharSet = CharSet.Unicode` in the attribute list of `dllimport`. Catch it as a `StringBuilder` rather than a string class.